# QueueClient.BeginReceive costs

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh851744.aspx), I can set even a 24 days long period for the [QueueClient.BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh322633.aspx) .
As we know, azure service bus is priced by storage transactions. I wonder if i set for example a 10days timeout for the beginreceive method, how many transactions are taken into count? 1? if it's not 1, how can i determinate it?

here is a little code sample, from my worker role. How is it priced?

```
public override void Run()
{
    updaterClient.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), updaterClientReceiveEnded, null);
    loggingQueueClient.BeginReceiveBatch(100, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), LoggingQueueClientReceiveEnded, null);

    while (!IsStopped)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
}

private async void updaterClientReceiveEnded(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var brokeredMessage = updaterClient.EndReceive(ar);
    if (brokeredMessage != null)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => Updater.Current.Update(brokeredMessage));
        await task;
    }
    updaterClient.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), updaterClientReceiveEnded, null);

}

private async void LoggingQueueClientReceiveEnded(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var brokeredMessages = loggingQueueClient.EndReceiveBatch(ar);
    if (brokeredMessages != null)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => LogUtil.Current.HandleMessages(brokeredMessages.ToList()));
        await task;
    }
    loggingQueueClient.BeginReceiveBatch(100, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), LoggingQueueClientReceiveEnded, null);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're charged per message (well $.01 per 10000 messages) so, if the operation resulted in one message, that's what you'd be charged for, regardless of how long it took.

for more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh667438.aspx#BKMK_SBv2FAQ2_2

Comment: actully. you're charged by request. a request resulted with no message is a billable unit. for example: if you use batch receive or send, you  can save money, cause you sent only one message (including all of the brokeredmessage). I just don't know, how these long polling models are priced.

Comment: @TamásVarga They don't mention batch in the pricing FAQ, do you have a reference to this?

Comment: That is for Windows Azure queues, not service bus queues.